# Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Este é um pequeno projeto para treinar(ele recomenda série de acordo com os dados)
e dá o seguinte erro no `value` ao clicar em 'ok':

```
Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'value' of null
```

código html:

```js
function ok() {
  var data = new Date()
  var ano = data.getFullYear()
  var fano = document.querySelector('txtidade')
  var res = document.querySelector('div#res')
  var img = document.createElement('img')
  img.setAttribute('id', 'foto')
  if (fano.value.length == 0 || Number(fano.value) > ano) {
    window.alert('[ERRO] DADO INVÁLIDO! VERIFIQUE E TENTE NOVAMENTE!')
  } else {
    var sex = document.getElementsByName('radsex')
    var idade = ano - Number(fano.value)
    var genero = ''
    var gosto = ''
    var periodo = ''
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Séries.com</title>
  <script src="interação.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>QUAL SÉRIE COMBINA COM VOCÊ?!</header>
  <section>
    <div>
      <p>
        Primeiro, digite o ano de seu nascimento:
        <input type="number" name="txtidade" id="txtidade" min="0">
      </p>
      <p>
        Sexo:
        <input type="radio" name="radsex" id="mas" checked>
        <label for="mas">Masculino</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radsex" id="fem">
        <label for="fem">Feminino</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radsex" id="outro">
        <label for="outro">outro</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        O que você prefere?
        <input type="radio" name="genre" id="misteri" checked>
        <label for="misteri">Mistério/suspense</label>
        <input type="radio" name="genre" id="comed">
        <label for="comed">Ação/comédia</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="period" id="dia" checked>
        <label for="dia">Dia</label>
        <input type="radio" name="period" id="noite">
        <label for="noite">Noite</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="OK!" onclick="ok()">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="res">
      Preencha e veja!
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; All rights reserveds</p>
  </footer>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="modelo.css">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Isso esta errado `var fano = document.querySelector('txtidade')`, faltou o `#` no selector do id `#txtidade`

Comment: Muito obrigado! Substituí o "queryselector" pelo "getElementsbyid" e também funcionou sem usar o # necessário no queryselector.

Comment: Se você encontrou uma solução para o seu problema poste como resposta e marque como resposta aceita para que a pergunta seja fechada e ajude outras pessoas também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituí o "queryselector" pelo "getElementsbyid" e também funcionou sem usar o # necessário no queryselector.